# $C(X\times Y) $separates points and vanishes nowhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that for $X,Y$ compact, that a subspace of $C(X\times Y$) , which is spanned by $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y), g\in C(X), h\in C(Y) $separates points and vanishes nowhere. I am having some difficulty thinking of a function for which never equals zero (i.e, nowhere vanishing) and a function such that for $a\neq b, f(a)\neq f(b) (i.e., $separates points$)),$where the function is an element of $C(X\times Y)$.

I *think* I can say it is nowhere vanishing because a constant would be in $X$, and all constants are nowhere vanishing as long they aren't the zero function.

I'm not sure of what function could make the subspace separate points though.

Could I get a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ Hausdorff?

Comment: @John: No. They are just compact metric spaces

Comment: @John, actually sorry, I believe they are. IF I remember correctly, all metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Not a problem, it's good to know that they are metric spaces. What do you mean that the subspace vanishes nowhere? Can you also state that in your question?

Comment: It's not given in the question that they do, but I suspect that they do, since the subspace is a subalgebra of $C(X\times Y)$, so I feel like the question is pushing me toward using Stone-Weierstrass. The version of Stone Weierstrass given in my book is that if I have a compact metric space $X$, and $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$, and if $A$ both separates points and vanishes nowhere, then $A$ is dense in $C(X)$. This question is part of a bigger problem I'm trying to do, i.e., I'm trying to show that the subspace is dense in $C(X,Y)$.

Comment: Yes, so by vanishing nowhere, it means to find a function in $A$ which is never zero. You are right that you can take constant function.

Comment: *Vanishing nowhere* means that there is no point in the space where all the functions in the subspace vanish, not that there is a non zero function. But constants are of course good.

Comment: @egreg: Now that I think about it, the functions I choose to show that it is both nowhere vanishing and separates points are $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$, so can I even choose a constant function? Shouldn't it have to be an ordered pair $(x,y):x\in X, y\in Y$?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: A constant function send $(x, y)$ to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying *a subspace $L$ of $C(X\times Y)$ vanishes nowhere* it might be clearer to say *for all $a\in X\times Y$ there is $f\in L$ with $f(a)\not= 0$* and as mentioned in the comments this is so since in your case $L$ contains all constant functions.

Concerning the separation of points, given $(x,y)\not= (\tilde x,\tilde y)$ then
$x\not= \tilde x$ or $y\not= \tilde y$. In the first case define $g(s)=d(s,x)$ 
(the distance on $X$) and $h(t)=1$. Then $f(s,t)=g(s)h(t)$ (that is $f=g\otimes h $) satisfies  $f(x,y)=0$ and $f(\tilde x,\tilde y)=d(\tilde x,x)\not=0$. The second case is the same.